# How to get the "process IDs" which are logging output to stdout?

Tags: process, stdout

How do I get the PIDs of all the processes which are dumping output to stdout.

Comment: Your request is unclear. do you mean processes that are currently and actively sending data to some tty ? processes that are currently feeding some pipe / socket / file via their stdout ? Or any process that is just capable of doing so occasionally ?

Comment: I mean processes that are currently and actively sending data to stdout.

Comment: So wherever the ouput goes (tty / input to some pipe / socket / file…) ?

Answer (score 9):

All processes are given a standard output and are liable to write to it. If you want to find those processes whose standard output is the current terminal, on Linux you can use

```
find -L /proc/[0-9]*/fd/1 -prune -samefile /dev/stdout
```

The similar

```
find -L /proc/[0-9]*/fd/2 -prune -samefile /dev/stdout
```

will identify processes whose standard error is the current terminal. You can combine both with

```
find -L /proc/[0-9]*/fd/[12] -prune -samefile /dev/stdout
```

That doesn’t tell you whether they’re actually writing to the current terminal however.

To actually log all PIDs writing to their standard out, you can use [bpftrace](https://bpftrace.org/), if your kernel supports eBPF (which many distribution kernels do now; see [the `bpftrace` kernel requirements](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/INSTALL.md#linux-kernel-requirements) for details):

```
sudo bpftrace -e 'kprobe:ksys_write /comm != "bpftrace" && arg0 == 1/ { printf("PID %d writing to stdout\n", pid); }'
```

This will log every write to standard out (file descriptor 1), except those coming from `bpftrace` itself (since this `bpftrace` program writes to standard out, it ends up just logging itself).

Comment: bpftrace ! +1 ! Splendid Stephen! I just want that ! Ha ! It seems I should first enable CONFIG_BPF , CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL, CONFIG_BPFILTER and CONFIG_BPF_JIT in my kernel .config. Probably worth mentioning. Nevermind ! Many thanks !

Comment: Or `find -L /proc/[1-9]*/fd/1 -prune -samefile /dev/stdout`  to catch other paths to the terminal. Or `print -rC1 /proc/<->/fd/1(e['[[ $REPLY -ef $TTY ]]']:h:h:t)` for the pids only in `zsh` (or `ps -fp` instead of `print -rC1` to get some information about the processes)

Comment: @MC68020 fair enough ;-). The same can be done with `ftrace`, I’ve been meaning to check out Steven Rostedt’s latest improvements to that.

Comment: `-prune` so `find` doesn't descend into directories for those processes that have a directory opened on fd 1. Now `-samefile` would account for hardlinks of `$(tty)` but not for copies, we'd need a `-samedevice`. See also `lsof -ad1 "$(tty)"` (working like `-samefile` AFAICT).

Comment: Would also not catch processes whose stdout is redirected to `/dev/tty` in the session where the controlling tty is `$(tty)`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed, and handling that would require decoding `/proc/…/stat`’s seventh field to determine whether the controlling tty is the same as the current tty.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike others, I believe your question does not make that much sense, or rather I suspect you made a mistake?

Stdout, very specifically, is just a file descriptor FD1.

Each process that has FD1 open, ie `/proc/self/fd/1` on linux, is potentially writing to stdout.

Is this really what you wanted to know?

If yes, then `bftrace` example of @Stephen Kitt is only way to get processes actually writing to FD1, but only those that write to it at the moment tracer filter runs.

If you are okay even with all the possible writers `sudo lsof | egrep ' 1u| 1w'` should do too (and returns much bigger set).

But if you are asking, what is writing into "current" `tty` (maybe the one you are seeing in terminal), that is completely different matter, because even if process closed FD1, it can have your tty open on any other FD, to be wild, even on FD777901700.

In that case you must identify tty in question and filter for that `sudo lsof | grep 'CHR' | grep '/dev/yourtty'`.